# How to convert a submodule to a jar and use it as a dependency rather than the project itself

Tags: gradle

My project has a two modules, an app module, and a lib module.

For my app I have the following in the app module's `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':my-lib')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

I would like to convert `my-lib` into a jar, and use the jar as the dependency rather than the module itself, so I added a `libs` folder in the parent folder of the `src` folder,

```
app
  AndroidManifest.xml
  build
  src
  res
  libs
```

added the jar to `libs` and defined the `libs` folder in the `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':my-lib')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
}

repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
   }
}
```

How can I instruct Gradle to use the jar? Is this the correct path?

Answer (score 0):

Changing this

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':my-lib')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

to this

```
dependencies {
    api files('libs/my-lib.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

seems to have worked